# vs2010 project not rebuilding properly

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, rebuild

I am rebuilding project first time and launch it. Works fine.
Then I change the code rebuild the project. Rebuild succeeded. I make a break-point at the project and launch in debugging mode. I do not see the changes an break-point does not hit. When I check the break-point it says: "**The breakpoint will not currently be hit. The source code is different from the original version." Why is this like that**?

- I have tried cleaning project and rebuilding it again.
- I have tried to delete everything from the debug folder.
- I have tried closing and opening vs2010.
- I have also tried to reset all vs2010 settings to default.

But nothing seems to help, the only thing that helps is when I restart my PC it rebuild properly and I can see the changes and the break-point hits.
Any ideas how to fix this issue?

I am working on a web project with asp.NET

Comment: Can you go to build output and see if there are any errors? Next: build from command line and see if that works.

Comment: I've had the exact same issue often as well with a large project, even though rebuild on changes are enabled. I just keep rebuilding until it works. I guess I need to someday look at all the build output in detail for issues. But it is a huge project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem. All I had to do was close from task manager vhost.exe process and it rebuild properly and I was able to hit the breakpoint. 
Although I'm not sure why the process was not closing as soon as I close the application and stop debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking the following options in vs2010 menus:

1. Tools -> Options -> Project and Solution -> Build and Run -> Check
   that "On run, when projects are out of date" is set to "Always
   build" or "Prompt to build".
2. Build -> Configuration Manager -> Check that "Build" is checked for
   all of the projects you want to build for each of the configurations
   you need to use.

I hope that will help you achieve a solution.